# Synchronizing handler creation, and accessing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

im getting sometimes null pointer exception while accessing handler created in thread.

I`m using two approaches.

One is service with thread, in which i create handler and access it by service method.
Second is Thread created in activity, in which i`m making Thread, starting it, and making handler.

Problem is quite simple, handler is created asynchronously to main thread. And i'am accessing it in main (gui thread), so sometimes it will create, and sometimes it will be null at time of getting it.

i could make on gui thread while(handler == null){
}
but it's really bad solution. I`m looking for some elegant way to do this.

Everything is in main thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable {
Looper.prepare();
handler = new Handler();
Looper.Loop();
}
handler.post(new Runnable{}) //at this point sometimes handler is still null. 
and it is created like few ms later. But still at this point i need valid handler
to background thread
```

Comment: Can you add your code please but I dont understand very well your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unless "hander" attribute is volatile, using a while-loop or sleeping is not only unelegant, but also wrong -  even if you find that handler is not null, you are not allowed to use it. Since there is no happens-before relation between writing to handler and creating hander instance, the main thread might see the reference to handler BEFORE ITS CONSTRUCTOR IS RUN;
2. A safe choice to hand off a simple reference is SynchronousQueue (it's not really a queue, it has no internal capacity, it's only there to move an object between threads). You would use it like so (off my head, some typos highly possible):

```
    final SynchronousQueue<Handler> giveMeHandler = new SynchronousQueue();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
          Handler handler;
          // create a Handler;
          giveMeHandler.put(handler); // blocks until handler taken;
       }

    }).start();

    Handler handler = giveMeHandler.take(); // blocks until handler given
```

Comment: btw: what you want to do IS stopping the GUI thread (for a very short time required to get the new handler). If you are serious about not stopping it at all, you have to create a callback and have the new thread give you its handler.

Comment: so basically im creating layout, etc, but every action i want to execute after handler is created i put in callback? right?

Comment: I don't really follow the question? I merely said that since you want to wait for the handler to be available, that's essentially "blocking". If you don't want to block at all (for whatever reason), you need to move the code that requires the handler to a method like "onHandlerCreated(Handler)"; then you runOnUiThread a call to that method. Things always work that way: you either block or switch to asynchronous calls. Frankly, I suspect that you are abusing Looper and should use an executor service instead (it's not really meant for passing upstream).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concurrent package of the java source.
Possible solutions:

- [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)
- [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

They encapsulate the synchronization logic for you.

Your code will look something like:

```
CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(2);
...
T1:
cb.await();
T2:
cb.await();
```

The CyclicBarrier (or CountDownLatch) will wait untill the given amount of threads (in this case 2) is awaiting the barrier.

Comment: well but i can't stop gui thread in java/android, or in other words i can but it's not a solution, not elegant at least. And moving all logic outside Gui thread would be painfull.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice we were talking about the update-thread. Well I'd suggest the use of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) then.

Comment: Well, AsyncTask is great for common and simple taks, i have to use Threads and their potential.